# Why doesn't this code related to finding common multiples work?

Tags: python, algorithm

Assignment:

> You are choreographing a circus show with various animals. For one act, you are given two kangaroos on a number line ready to jump in the positive direction (i.e, toward positive infinity).
>
> The first kangaroo starts at location `x1`  and moves at a rate of `v1` meters per jump.
>   The second kangaroo starts at location `x2`  and moves at a rate of `v2` meters per jump.
>
> You have to figure out a way to get both kangaroos at the same location at the same time as part of the show. If it is possible, return `YES`, otherwise return `NO`.

How I can replace the `while m < 1000` line in the given code to extend the search limits.

I executed the given code on Pycharm. I found that no execution.

```
x1 = 0
v1 = 3
mul1 = 0              # Multiple of Kangaroo 1
a = []             # Multiples of Kangaroo 1 List
x2 = 4
v2 = 2
mul2 = 0              # Multiple of Kangaroo 2
b = []             # Multiples of Kangaroo 2 List
m = 0
while m < 10000:                    # Limited search
    i = 0
    mul1 += x1 + (i*v1)
    a.append(mul1)
    mul2 += x2 + (i*v2)
    b.append(mul2)
    i += 1
    conj = list(set(a).intersection(b))             # List of common elements
    if len(conj) > 0:                        # Checking if conj has some values
        for x in range(len(conj)):
            print(conj[x])                # Prints common value
        break
    m += 1
```

I need to get

```
YES
```

if I input

```
0
3
4
2
```

And I need to get

```
NO
```

if I input

```
0
2
5
3
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem a simpler way.

Assuming that the roos jump at the same speed (both have the same number of jumps per minute, just each can have different distance per jump), you have the following (in math terms):

```
x_final = x1 + v1 * num_jumps
x_final = x2 + v2 * num_jumps
```

Doing some restructuring (in math terms), we get this:

```
x1 + v1 * num_jumps = x2 + v2 * num_jumps
x1 - x2 = v2 * num_jumps - v1 * num_jumps
x1 - x2 = (v2 - v1) * num_jumps
(x1 - x2) / (v2 - v1) = num_jumps
```

Now with values

```
x1 = 0
v1 = 3
x2 = 4
v2 = 2
(x1 - x2) / (v2 - v1) = num_jumps
(0 - 4) / (2 - 3) = num_jumps
(-4) / (-1) = num_jumps
4 = num_jumps
```

Here `num_jumps` is positive, so they will meet.

```
x1 = 0
v1 = 2
x2 = 5
v2 = 3
(x1 - x2) / (v2 - v1) = num_jumps
(0 - 5) / (3 - 2) = num_jumps
(-5) / 1 = num_jumps
-5 = num_jumps
```

Here `num_jumps` is negative, so they will never meet.

---

A `Python` function to solve this:

```
def will_they_meet(x1, v1, x2, v2):
    num_jumps = (x1 - x2) / (v2 - v1)
    return 'YES' if num_jumps >= 0 else 'NO'
```

Note: this code may raise errors if `v1` and `v2` are equal (`ZeroDivisionError`) of if the arguments passed to the function are not numbers. You may need to add your `try`...`except` blocks to make it more robust.

As you can see, there is no need to generate all the possible positions and no need for a any kind of loop.

Comment: The question asks about jumping kangaroos, not walking elephants

Comment: @MattTimmermans The question askes `How I can replace the while m < 1000 line in the given code to extend the search limits?`, so I gave a possible solution to replace the loop construct.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the 2 equations is actually much faster (and simpler than iterating) as the solution may be arbitrarily far in the future. This runs in **`O(1)` time and space**.

```
def solve(x1, v1, x2, v2):
    if v1 == v2:
        # If same start       -> always together (True)
        # If different start  -> will never meet (False)
        return x1 == x2
    else:
        t = (x2 - x1) / (v1 - v2)
        # Will only meet if the intersection happens in the future
        return t >= 0

def main():
    x1 = 0
    v1 = 3
    x2 = 4
    v2 = 2

    print('YES' if solve(x1, v1, x2, v2) else 'NO')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```